# Google Cloud: Releasing Static IP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to release the static IP that I don't want anymore. I found the documentation that leads me to "External IP addresses".

When I select the External IP that I want to release, the "RELEASE STATIC ADDRESS" button does not get enabled.

Also, when I hover over to it, the message reads "To release the IP address, choose the static address that is not in use". My instance is not ON.

Will appreciate your help on this. I have attached the image for your reference.

[image: EXTERNAL IP ADDRESS DASH]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't release this static IP because it is still in use by "instance-1".
Go on instance-1 configuration and change static ip with ephemeral ip. Then go back to External Ip Addresses configuration and remove your static ip.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't realize there was a step before the final step.